Can the same arguments used to reject metaphysical solipsism also support accepting the existence of God?
Why do most people reject metaphysical solipsism and instead accept the reality of an external world? There are two primary reasons:

The perception of having repeated conscious experiences of an external world.
A strong intuition that one’s conscious experiences are real and reliable.

While a solipsist might still be able to rebut these intuitions (here is a chat debate in which I play devil's advocate for metaphysical solipsism—quite successfully, I would say, if you are interested (EDIT: follow-up discussion with the same user here)), intuitively, (1) and (2) remain strong pragmatic and intuitive reasons why people believe the things around them exist.
By the same token, wouldn't it be conceivable that (1) and (2) might also hold for the existence of God? Namely, that there could be some people, even if just a tiny fraction of the global population, who have managed to establish a direct relationship with God in which (1) and (2) apply. As a result, these individuals might perceive a strong experiential intuition to accept the existence of God, just as the average person experiences a strong experiential intuition to accept the existence of the external world.
Why wouldn't this be a plausible reason for being a theist, even if it applies only to a small fraction of people who are fortunate enough to experience such a privileged epistemic state of affairs?

"Why wouldn't this be a plausible reason for being a theist...?" Who says it isn't though? Most people believe in a great many things they haven't directly experienced.

Most philosophers were realists about external world long before the recent focus on "conscious experiences", which only emerged in debates over physicalism since 1950s. So those two reasons are certainly not "primary", and it is unclear why the second is relevant at all, it is compatible with solipsism. If there is a 'primary' reason it is that people are routinely affected by something they have no control over and "conscious experiences" as such are not particularly salient to it. And there is a big leap from concrete external influences to God so the answer to the title question is no.

'For it is by grace you have been saved, through faith—and this is not from yourselves, it is the gift of God' seems to indicate that something analogous to what you describe has described Christian theism since the beginning.

If solipsism is incorrect because there really are lots of people, then why isn't monotheism also incorrect?

Your 1st para is a flag that invites closure. Change it to something like Which notable philosophers have observed that...

@Rushi I'm not sure what edit you are proposing, but feel free to edit it yourself.

@Rushi But what would you write after "Which notable philosophers have observed that..."? Can you write the whole sentence?

Perhaps something like ... observed that both the rejection of solupsism and the affirmation of theism follow from similar more primitive assumptions Personally I'd prefer deism to theism but I'm not going to struggle to de-christisnize this site

@Rushi: Should we be saying adeistic, then?

This observation does suggest strong counters to arguments against God. For example, if the atheist argues:

We can explain everything that happens without reference to God. Since God is an
additional hypothesis, beyond what is needed to explain what we
observe, we should discard him as a hypothesis.

You can construct a parallel argument like this:

We can explain everything we experience without reference to an
external world. Since the external world is an additional hypothesis,
beyond what is needed to explain what we experience, we should discard
it as a hypothesis.

Both arguments have the same form, so the atheist is forced to either discard his argument or argue that

We can explain everything that happens without reference to God.

is on firmer ground than

We can explain everything we experience without reference to an external world.

This is a tall order, especially since we actually can't explain everything that happens, with or without reference to God.
Here's another example. The atheist argues:

When people have experiences of talking with God or seeing God at
work, it's simpler to just assume they are hallucinating and there
is no actual God there.

The obvious response is:

When you think you are drinking a cup of coffee it is simpler to
just assume you are hallucinating and there is no actual cup of
coffee there.

Solipsism is the simpler explanation at least in the sense that it requires fewer entities. Which suggests another common example:

Your theory of God requires everything that my theory requires:
matter, forces, etc. and in addition you require an additional entity,
so your theory is more complex. You should just discard the additional
entity.

Answerable by:

Your theory of an outside world requires everything that my theory
requires, a mind and mental events, and in addition you require an
additional entity, so your theory is more complex. You should discard
the additional entity.

Another example:

Your strong intuition that life and the universe in general show
a deliberate design is unfalsifiable and therefore unscientific,
and since science is the measure of all things, your intuition
has no value.

Can be countered with

Your strong intuition that the things you experience are real
is unfalsifiable and therefore unscientific, and since science
is the measure of all things, your intuition has no value.

It's less clear that it can stand as a strong positive argument, a strong argument for the existence of God. It can, perhaps be used in a weak positive argument in this form:

I believe in God because (G1) I have a strong intuition that he causes
things I see in the world and because (G2) I have experienced
communicating with him. I believe in the outer world because (E1) I
have a strong intuition that when I perceive a physical object, it is
because that object caused my perception, and because (E2) I have
experienced the outer world. Since G1 is directly analogous to E1 and
G2 to E2, if E1 and E2 are sufficient to make me believe, then G1 and
G2 should be sufficient to make me believe.


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Imagine your mother is in the room. You now leave the room. You come back to the room and see her. Solipsism has no explanation for why your mother is still there. The external world theory does. It makes sense of your experiences and can predict your experiences in a way that solipsism cannot. Solipsism is discounted not just because it “feels wrong” but because it has a lack of explanatory and predictive power.
But a lack of explanatory power cannot be used to justify the existence of anything, much less god. It is usually used as a justification to dismiss a hypothesis. A lack of explanatory and predictive power is one of the main reasons atheists use to deny or dismiss god.

There are sources of cause that are not in control of the will. We take those sources of cause to be persistent in external reality for the time-being. The mind makes up external reality from personal experience.

I think there might be a misunderstanding about what solipsism claims. To my understanding,  solipsism doesn't deny that our experiences are consistent and predictable - it just proposes that these consistent experiences, including things like seeing your mother when returning to a room, can be explained as features of consciousness rather than evidence of an external world. A solipsist would say that the persistence and predictability of phenomena are simply properties of the conscious experience itself.

@DanielB Can you give a solipsistic explanatory account of why my mother is still there in the room from start to finish?

@Syed Your mother was not there in the first place because time is an illusion. You are begging the question by assuming the existence of time. See our chat discussion here.

@user80226 As mentioned in my other comment, assuming the existence of time gives an explanation for why our experiences follow patterns than without. So we should assume the existence of, or atleast the experience of time, for the same reason we should prefer the existence of an external world over solipsism. It helps us explain more

@Syed How do you "know" there are patterns? For the solipsist, it is just an illusion from your memories in the present moment.

@user80226 again, it’s about experience, not what is actual. We experience patterns. You can claim that it is an illusion. But if it is an illusion, the patterns become unexplained. On the other hand, an external world combined with laws acting on those objects that creates those patterns make them explained.

@Syed How do you explain your laws, your psycho-physical laws (to solve the hard problem of consciousness), your initial conditions and your random events? If you claim they are necessary, why not save multiple steps and just claim that patterns in memories in the present moment are necessary?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Real existence has no more explanatory power than solipsism does. Just saying "the chair is really there" doesn't imply it will be there a second from now. Real objects could just flash in and out of existence. You are putting on the realism side an entire, very complex theory of how real objects work and denying the solipsism side any theory that would explain the same phenomena.

"Can you give a solipsistic explanatory account of why my mother is still there in the room from start to finish?" I'm not sure I understand what there is to explain. At least in the version of solipsism I understand, your consciousness has invented the room and the entity you think of as your mom. It has no trouble displaying her for you again when you re-enter the room, and inventing chains of consequences for what she might have been up to in the meantime.

If I'm writing a story where Alice exits a room that Bob is in, and then re-enters, I do not need to believe that Alice and Bob are real in order to have Bob still be in that room.

@DanielB When I come back in the room, why do I see my mom instead of a cat, or a dog, or anything else?

@Syed I think the rationale is that internal narrative consistency is a property of the imagined reality. Or at the very least, an internal sense that said consistency exists.

@DanielB then that begs the question of why there is a desire to keep an internal narrative within your conscious experience that obeys laws. This is left unexplained but explained by the external world theory so solipsism still loses out

@Syed In what way does it beg the question? I’m not seeing where I’m assuming the premise. And there’s no need for a desire for consistency. The external world has rules, causality and consistency, there’s no reason the inside world can’t.

@DanielB the external world also has posits (such as the existence of mind independent objects) that explain the persistence of an object in experience. Again, can you give a solipsistic account of this? By begging the question I meant that you’re restating the problem. Saying that an internal rule based narrative is part of your conscious experience doesn’t explain why the phone stays in the room when you come back and visit the room. You have to elaborate how that works. We have a how in the external world theory

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Your statement (2) is problematic as I'm not sure how we'd get to (2) without the truth of (1). So I really think it is (1) that is operative here.
For God, the analogy breaks precisely due to (1): The perception of having repeated conscious experiences of an God.
If I did have (1) then I would almost certainly be a theist, as would many present atheists and naturalists since "divine hiddenness" would not be a thing.  I don't doubt the existence of the Sun exactly because of (1).
I am fundamentally empirical as I don't trust purely "rational" thought given how it likely came about in evolution ;)
So, yeah, if I repeatedly experienced God in a direct way, I'd be hard pressed to maintain my atheism. However, my experience of repeatedly hearing about mental disorders would first make me want to double check my experiences with others. If a bunch of us are all having these experiences, then I'd be inclined to accept it as true.

Yes, mental illnesses can explain a few repeatable experiences of communication with god, but cannot if everyone else was experiencing the same thing. The problem is that the latter has never happened

@Syed correct and hence I’m an  atheist

@Syed They can explain it to some extent. If there's a common cultural expectation of what "communication with God" is, then it's likely that different people will both have something like that through the power of suggestion. And if mental illnesses have common symptoms, people might interpret those symptoms as a "communication with God", and then have the same "experience".

The fault in your reasoning lies in your assumption that the two primary reasons for rejecting solipsism are the two you mention. They are not the reasons why I reject solipsism.
Putting your argument about solipsism as far to one side as possible, if you consider the real reasons why people believe much of what they do, you will find that they largely believe what they have been told provided it is not inconsistent or denied by direct personal experience. I believe, for example, that the Earth is round, that Australia is on the other side of it, that men have landed on the moon, that hardened arteries are a major cause of death, that the Nile is not in Somerset, that Margaret Thatcher is dead, and so on, even though I have never had direct personal experience of any of those assorted phenomena. I stopped believing in Father Christmas- notwithstanding the fact that I had been assured he exists-because I realised his existence was logically inconsistent with everything else I had learned, such as the inadequate capacity of a sleigh for the purpose of enabling simultaneous deliveries of presents to millions of households.
I suspect, therefore, that many people hold religious beliefs because they were drummed into them as children. That, at least, explains the reason why a child's religious beliefs are commonly observed to be those of their parents. If someone, having been assured of the existence of God, has direct personal experiences of what they believe to be an interaction with God, you can understand why they believe in him.
The more notable parallel between God and solipsism is the fact that logic alone is never sufficient to persuade some people that they are nonsense.

Epistemological solipsism is the metaphysical source of all knowledge and efforts to communicate. Calling it nonsense simply means one has not gone to the source of knowledge and personal experience. God is just as real as anything else arising at the source. Sigmund Freud, for example, rejects the religion of his father, and frames Jewish and Christian theology as the psychological projection of an infantile wish for the protection of the father. Yet Freud is also a giant former infant, according to his own theories, who does not experience God and who claims superior knowledge of reality!

@SystemTheory wait, what?

@ScottRowe - I don't know what what? means. Is God real or not real? Does Freud have superior or inferior knowledge of reality compared to his Jewish father(s)? The first distinction, at the source of my own subjective knowledge, is between the empty and populated field of awareness. In the empty field of awareness God is neither real nor not real. People report their subjective experiences arising in the populated field of awareness: God, Real, True or God, Real, False! If I search for the source of cause of awareness it only generates possibly true or false items of recognition in my mind.

@SystemTheory classic symptoms of seeing both sides of the "Two Truths Doctrine". Carry on.

@ScottRowe - I hold that ultimate reality is unknowable in the empty field of awareness. This is the Zen experience of not-knowing. I think the theory of two truths (TTT) claims personal knowledge of ultimate reality alongside folk psychological reality. I know many things about my experience of reality but do not know anything about ultimate reality. Anything I claim to know is a belief formed inside my personal experience. Both knowing and not knowing are true and that might be something like Buddhist TTT. The Jewish fathers live in a different reality than the godless Sigmund Freud.

@SystemTheory yeah, as far as I can tell I reasonably agree with you. I tend to say less rather than more, it keeps me out of trouble. What if I did actually, truly understand something, would I be able to convey it to someone who doesn't? I found this while teaching - I can present info, but I can't guarantee to transmit understanding. It is "outside the scriptures", as the Zen folks say. Well, yeah, that's life.

Solipsism claims that the external world doesn't exist and is just in the imagination of the solipsist. If that is true the solipsist's mind is an extremely large and complex system that acts just like the external world whose existence he denies. So solipsism is just realism with a different label on the external world.
A person who claims to have encountered God may be lying or may have mistaken some internally generated experience for an experience of God. These experiences are all of the sort one could explain by them being internally generated. People who see God can't suddenly explain the solution to the problem of quantum gravity or factorise large products of primes with unknown prime factors or do anything else that would indicate that anything outside of the capabilities of a person in our cultural context. And we know that people claiming to have seen God have done no such thing because if there was even the appearance of such an event we would never hear the end of it even if it was later debunked.

A person might form the belief that only matter and light exist in the external world. The bodies of animals, children, and adult humans therefore consist of nothing more or less than physical interactions of matter and light. This is a model of the external world in the minds of some humans that does not exist in the minds of animals or young children. Epistemological solipsism is not refuted by forming models of the external world derived from qualia and concepts arising in the mind. On the contrary it is confirmed by recognizing that models of reality arise only in one's subjective context.

Yes, and you can reject both for the same reason
For a hypothesis to be worth considering, it must make (theoretically) falsifiable predictions. Since neither can, they are both worthy of equal (and near zero) consideration.

Let A denote the otherwise empty field of awareness. Sources of cause map to conventional terms as follows:
A = Man
A = Nature
A = Reality
A = God
A = Unconscious
A = Exist, Not Exist
Man is a source of cause in the context of folk psychology, ethics, morality, and law. We generate the awareness of human agents as a source of cause.
Nature is a source of cause in the context of folk psychology, ethics, morality, and law. We recognize natural events as distinct from human agents. The distinction can be fuzzy or vague in context. For example a person suffers a heart attack while driving. If there is no reason for the person to foresee this natural event then the person driving is not legally responsible for causing harm to others when they lose consciousness. There are natural events (conditions) that enable Man to be responsible; and there are natural events (conditons) that excuse Man from responsibility.
If we rule out human agents as the source of cause then we are left with the other items of recognition: Natural Events, Reality, God, or something unknown and therefore in psychology it is called the Unconscious.
Ultimately we observe events and generate narratives. People make up the concepts of exist or does not exist and map other concepts onto those categories. I say shit happens and people make up stories.
